# Function Shell Script no return data

Tags: linux, bash, shell

```
function ping {
nome=$(dialog --title "Inform o endereço que deseja PINGAR" --inputbox "IP ou URL - \
    Lembrando que será disparado 10 pings para o endereço informado." 10 45 --stdout)
status=$?
if [[ $status -eq 0 ]]; then
    ping -c 10 $nome
    rc=$?
    if [[ $rc -eq 0 ]]; then
        echo "#####################################"
        echo "## Endereço: $nome | Status: UP"  
        echo "#####################################"
    else
        echo "#####################################"
        echo "## Endereço: $nome | Status: DOWN"
        echo "#####################################"
    fi
else
    echo "Você optou por cancelar a operação."
fi }; valor=`ping`; echo "RESULTADO FOI: "$valor
```

When i run the script (`./meuscript.sh`), I have no return, only if i select cancel the dialog.

If I run the script without the function, the command is executed correctly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an endless loop.  Rename the function to something else so that you don't end up with `ping` calling `ping` calling `ping` calling `ping`...

Additionally, you probably want to refactor your script substantially.  Anything that looks like

```
command
if [[ $? == 0 ]]; then
    stuff
fi
```

is better written

```
if command; then
    stuff
fi
```

so you end up with something like

```
function renamed_ping {
    if nome=$(dialog --title "Inform o endereço que deseja PINGAR" --inputbox "IP ou URL - \
    Lembrando que será disparado 10 pings para o endereço informado." 10 45 --stdout); then
        if ping -c 10 "$nome"; then
            status="UP"
        else
            status="DOWN"
        fi
        echo "#####################################"
        echo "## Endereço: $nome | Status: $status"  
        echo "#####################################"
    else
        echo "Você optou por cancelar a operação."
    fi
}

echo "RESULTADO FOI: $(renamed_ping)"
```

I also took the liberty to add [proper quoting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-variable), and factor out a needless variable, and remove the irregularities in the indentation.

(Having the function `echo` stuff and capturing it so you can `echo` it is still a bad smell, but then this looks like one of your first scripting exercises.)

Comment: Perfect, thank you for your help. You're right, I'm still learning!